# Shortcut to custom document properties in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, field-codes

I often need to edit the values of several (around five) custom document properties in Word documents.

In order to do that, I need to do this:

[image: click File]
[image: click Info]
[image: click Properties]
[image: click Advanced Properties]
[image: click Custom, then the property of interest]

**Is there a shortcut to do this faster?**

I'm hoping for a keyboard shortcut or a button, possibly even a text field in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Choose a Ribbon bar (View is probably the most appropriate)
2. Right-click in the empty space to the right, and choose 'Customize the Ribbon'

[image]

3. In the right-hand pane, under View click 'New Group'.
4. Rename it to something like 'Document Properties'

[image]

1. Change the drop-down in the left panel to 'Commands not in the ribbon'
2. Find 'Advanced Document Properties' and 'Add > >' to your new group, then click OK

[image]

You now have a 'View Document Properties' button on your View ribbon. When you click that, you're taken to the Properties dialog you were looking to navigate to

[image]

Comment: It can also be found under All Commands as FileProperties.

Answer (score 0):

Spikey_richey gave you a good answer.

It is also possible to add it to your Quick Access Toolbar.

In Recent versions this command is found under Commands not in the Ribbon as View Document Properties.

[image: screenshot]

In earlier versions, it was found under All Commands as Advanced Document Properties.

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link to a .dotx template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e75v38f7w3ue1wz/QATAdvancedDocumentProperties.dotx?dl=0) that can be used as an Add-In to add it to the QAT. It also has a couple of keyboard shortcuts that will work. Simply place the template in your Word Startup folder. Next time you start Word, you will have a button on your QAT for the (Advanced) Document Properties dialog.